# How to show that $|z_1+z_2|+|z_1-z_2| = |z_1+\sqrt{z^2_1-z^2_2} |+|z_1-\sqrt{z^2_1-z^2_2} | $?

Tags: complex-numbers

How to show that $$|z_1+z_2|+|z_1-z_2| = |z_1+\sqrt{z^2_1-z^2_2} |+|z_1-\sqrt{z^2_1-z^2_2} | $$

Is this question correct?

I tried my best to prove it

But got nowhere near, Any help

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h601290p3570423 on AoPS.

Comment: Doesn't make sense if $z_2>z_1>0$. Maybe we are in the complex field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=z_1+z_2$ and $b=z_1-z_2$, then we want to show that
$$|a|+|b|=\left|\frac{a+b}{2}+\sqrt{ab}\right|+\left|\frac{a+b}{2}-\sqrt{ab}\right|=\frac{1}{2}\left|\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\right|^2+\frac{1}{2}\left|\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}\right|^2$$
Now we know that
\begin{align*}
|z+w|^2 & =(z+w)(\bar{z}+\bar{w})=|z|^2+2(z\bar{w}+w\bar{z})+|w|^2\\
|z-w|^2 & =(z-w)(\bar{z}-\bar{w})=|z|^2-2(z\bar{w}+w\bar{z})+|w|^2
\end{align*}
Let $z=\sqrt{a}$ and $w=\sqrt{b}$. Recall that $\left| \sqrt{a}\right|^2=\left|(\sqrt{a})^2\right|=|a|$. Hopefully you can take it from here.

Comment: Sorry. How you got that second part ?

Comment: @AngeloMark which second part are you referring to?

Comment: $\left|\frac{a+b}{2}+\sqrt{ab}\right|+\left|\frac{a-b}{2}-\sqrt{ab}\right|$

Comment: Okay got it :) Thanks

Comment: @AngeloMark using the substitution I have described we can solve for $z_1=\frac{a+b}{2}$ and $z_2=\frac{a-b}{2}$. Also $ab=(z_1+z_2)(z_2-z_2)=z_1^2-z_2^2$. Then substitute these in the RHS of the expression we have to prove. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah got it :) Thanks . Big help

Comment: This surely can all be justified, but given that $\sqrt{ab}$, $\sqrt a$ and $\sqrt b$ can have *two* values I would be a bit more careful with the argumentation.